# Getting unexpected results when using synonyms

Tags: elasticsearch

I am using the following synonym definition:

"medals, medal => metals,medals,medal count, most medals"

When I search "Medals" in the title field, documents like "Armenia Medals, Diving Medals, etc" score higher than a document with a title of "Medals". Since Medals is an exact match I would expect it to be ranked the highest but it isn't. Does anyone have any explanation for this?

I'm using a edge ngram (1 to 50) when indexing documents and the standard analyzer when searching.

Mapping:

```
"title":{
      "type": "text",
      "analyzer": "full_search_analyzer",
      "search_analyzer": "standard", 
      "fields": {
        "keyword":{
          "type": "keyword"
        }
      }
    }
"sport_name":{
      "type": "text",
      "analyzer": "full_search_analyzer", 
      "search_analyzer": "standard",
      "fields": {
        "keyword":{
          "type": "keyword"
        }
      }
    },
    "country_name":{
      "type": "text",
      "analyzer": "full_search_analyzer",
      "search_analyzer": "standard",
      "fields": {
        "keyword":{
          "type": "keyword"
        }
      }
    },
```

Query:

```
query: {
         bool: {
           must:[{
             "multi_match": {
                 "query": "medals",
                      "fields": "title^2", "sport_name", "country_name",
                                    "minimum_should_match": "100%"
                                }                                
                            }],
                            should: {
                                term: {
                                    title: "Medals"
                                }
                            },
                            filter: {
                                term: {
                                    hideFullResults : false
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    },
```

The query is in a node app.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please add mapping and query

Comment: Thanks @jaspreetchahal, I added my mapping and query.